# How to detect corruption in PDFs

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm using iText7 for .NET and C# to manipulate PDFs. I would like to detect PDFs that generate errors like "Bad Parameter" and "There was a problem reading this document (15)." Using iText7, I can re-write PDFs with this type of error without triggering an exception,

```
try
{
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
    pdfR = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    PDFPages = pdfR.GetNumberOfPages();
    if (Functions.isPortfolio(pdfR)) throw new Exception("Can't process PDF portfolios");
    string sizes = string.Empty;
    string size = string.Empty;
    for (int page = 1; page <= PDFPages; page++)
    {
        size = Functions.getPDFPageSize(pdfR, page);
        if (sizes.Contains(size) == false) sizes += ", " + size;
    }
    sizes = sizes.Substring(2);
    PDFentry temp = PDFList[entry];
    temp.PageCount = PDFPages;
    temp.PageSizes = sizes;
    PDFList[entry] = temp;
    pageCount += PDFPages;
    if (Settings.Default.CheckRewrite)
    {
        tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(tempFile);
        var pdfW = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        pdfR.CopyPagesTo(1, PDFPages, pdfW);
        pdfW.Close();
        pdfR.Close();
        File.Copy(tempFile, pdfFile, overwrite: true);
    }
    else
    {
        pdfR.Close();
    }
}
```

and the copied result are inevitably corruption free, but I'd like to test and rewrite only the PDFs that are indeed corrupted. My experience with the iText library is quite limited, but what methods can I use to detect corruption in PDF files?

Comment: "Corrupted" PDF files which your code can fix most likely are corrupted in quite specific ways. For most corrupted PDFs I would assume that your code either finishes with an exception or the result is still corrupted. Thus, it is quite likely that the special kind of corruption your PDF corpus suffers from might be identifiable. For this end, though, representative PDFs are needed for analysis.

Comment: There's a kind of subtle corruption that allows you to open the PDF, navigate its pages, even print, but if you try to combine it with other PDFs or try to extract pages from it (in Tools, Organize, for example), you get an error message. I'll try to collect representative PDFs. I have so far only one, but it's 20 MB.

Comment: *"I have so far only one, but it's 20 MB."* - If you can share it online and post an URL here, that's ok.